# Why mariadb partitioning doesn't give me better performance?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Greeting.

Let me show my table scheme first:

```
CREATE TABLE `log_table` (
`rid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dataId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`memberId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`clientId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`qty` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`typeA` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`typeB` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`rid`,`timestamp`),
KEY `idx_report1` (`timestamp`,`memberId`,`dataId`),
KEY `idx_report2` (`memberId`,`timestamp`),
KEY `idx_report3` (`dataId`,`timestamp`,`rid`),
KEY `idx_report4` (`timestamp`,`typeB`,`typeA`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE (year(`timestamp`))
(PARTITION p2014 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),
 PARTITION p2015 VALUES LESS THAN (2016)
);
```

I'm using MariaDB 5.5 and this table contains 25 million records, so I decided to make partitions in the table for preventing performance issue may occur in the near future.
You may see it's time serial, log data, and having 4 views. For example, one of the views uses following query:

```
select typeB, typeA, count(*) as number from log_table where timestamp between '2015-1-1' and '2015-2-1' group by typeB, typeA;
```

AFAIK, this query loads the data from p2015 only by partition pruning. But I saw there is not much difference between original table and partition-version in query execution time. (avg 1.94 sec vs 1.95 sec)

Hm, I thought it's might influenced by number of rows in each partition. then how about smaller size of partition? to_days()?

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(`timestamp`))
(
...
PARTITION p_2015_01 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2015-2-1')),
PARTITION p_2015_02 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2015-3-1'))
...
)
```

Well, there's no effect. Could you let me know what's my missing piece?

---

EDIT: sorry for my error in the query.. btw, EXPLAIN PARTITION doesn't help me.

and result of explain both tables are :

```
// original
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys           | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | org_table | range | idx_report1,idx_report4 | idx_report4 | 8       | NULL | 8828000 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+


//partition
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys           | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | log_table | range | idx_report1,idx_report4 | idx_report4 | 8       | NULL | 7902646 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what does your explain plan look like for the queries? btw kudos on the nice post +1

Comment: There is no recdate field in your table. So, can you pls update the query or the create table to match each other? Pls post the results for the explains of both queries. I suspect that the recdate field is indexed plus the records are stored grouped together by date anyway in a log table, hence the little difference in execution time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PARTITIONing` does not help performance nearly as often as users think it will.

```
KEY `idx_report4` (`timestamp`,`typeB`,`typeA`)
```

without partitioning is optimal for the `SELECT` you provided.  `PARTITIONing` will not speed it up any.

Since `BETWEEN` is "inclusive" `where timestamp between '2015-1-1' and '2015-2-1'` actually hits two partitions.  Use `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...` to see that.

`BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(...))` is probably better than `BY RANGE (YEAR(...))`, but still not useful for the given query.

Here is my discussion of the *only* 4 use cases where `PARTITIONing` helps performance:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

If this type of query is important, consider "Summary Tables" as a way of greatly speeding up the application:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: Thanks for your answer.